# ValidationError: Graph must be in single static assignment (SSA) form, however 'layer1_0_relu0_fwd' has been used as output names multiple times

Tags: mxnet, gluon, onnx

When converting MXNet i3d_resnet50_v1_custom model to onxx I got an error like this:

```
ValidationError: Graph must be in single static assignment (SSA) form, however 'layer1_0_relu0_fwd' has been used as output names multiple times.
```

onxx version I used: 1.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixed with the help of [github discussion](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/discussions/20205).

1. Installing the onnx and support library

   !apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev

   !pip install onnx==1.7
2. Cloning the mxnet v1.x

   !rm -r incubator-mxnet

   !git clone -b v1.x --single-branch https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git
3. Building the wheel

   %cd /content/incubator-mxnet/python/mxnet/onnx/

   !python setup.py install --force
4. Finally importing and using

   import mx2onnx